# Firebase Rules Property email is undefined on object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set up my firestore rules and I am trying to make sure that the authenticated user's email is part of the team. For some reason firestore doesn't think that `request.auth` has an `email` property. Is this a bug for firebase or am I overlooking something?

[image: Firebase Rules Playground]

Answer (score 2):

It should be `request.auth.token.email`.